# How to make factories work well with Guice?

Tags: dependency-injection, guice, factory

In my project, I use dependency injection everywhere, and I use ad hoc factories for two cases. First, when I want to control exactly when an instance is created, I inject a factory instead of an instance:

```java
// WidgetA must be created before WidgetB, because of the side-effects
// on the container.
WidgetAFactory.make(container);
WidgetBFactory.make(container);
```

The other case is when the constructor takes a mix of injectable values and runtime values. Instead of using:

```java
@Inject
WidgetC(
    Container,
    @WidgetCFont Font,
    @WidgetCColor Color,
    @Named("flag") String flag) {
  ...
}
```

I use:

```java
@Inject
WidgetCFactory(
    @WidgetCFont Font font,
    @WidgetCColor Color color,
    @Named("flag") String flag) {
  ...
}

WidgetCFactory.make(Container container) {
 return new WidgetC(container, font, color, flag);
}
```

But I am being hit by two limitations with my use of factories:

1. In my first exanple, I also need WidgetA to be a @Singleton that will be needed by other @Injected constructors. So far, my solution is to store the instance I created when calling the factory, and @Provides it for others to use. Is there a way to give the control of this singleton back to guice without having to maintain that instance myself?
2. In my second example, managing the injected dependencies is a mess: the WidgetCFactory has to call the WidgetC constructor with a long list of injected values, that has to be updated for each change in the dependencies, with no annotation checks. Is there a way to provide Guice with the runtime parameter, and let it deal with the other dependencies?

It feels like for both cases, I could use a child injector that would be given the runtime value, and let Guice be the factory:

```java
public static class WidgetCFactory {
  private final Injector injector;

  @Inject
  public WidgetCFactory(Injector injector) {
    this.injector = injector;
  }

  public WidgetC make(Container container) {
    Injector childInjector = injector.createChildInjector(new AbstractModule() {
      @Override protected void configure() {
        bind(Container.class).toInstance(container);
      }
    });
    return childInjector.getInstance(WidgetC.class);
  }
}
```

But I don't find a lot of cases of people doing this. Is it because it's too heavy, or outside the good practices of dependency injection? What would be a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mixing injected and runtime values means you should look into "assisted injection", which lets you declare certain injected values to be provided at runtime by the callsite, and for a factory to be generated which will expose only those as a parameter. From https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AssistedInject, you'll want to install a module for each type to be handled in this way, something like

```
// this goes in your existing Module.configure()
install(new FactoryModuleBuilder()
     // you can add more than one type here in this way
     .implement(WidgetC.class, WidgetC.class)
     .build(WidgetFactory.class));

//...

public interface WidgetFactory {
    // you can add more than one method here 
    WidgetC createWidgetC(Container container);
}

@AssistedInject
WidgetC(
    @Assisted Container,
    @WidgetCFont Font,
    @WidgetCColor Color,
    @Named("flag") String flag) {
  ...
}
```

Note especially the change to the `WidgetC` constructor, both the different annotation on the constructor (since it is not in fact safe to construct via normal injection) and on the `Container` parameter (which will be provided by the factory, not the IoC container.

---

To make `WidgetA` a singleton, you can either decorate the type with `@Singleton`, or bind it in your `configure()` method:

```
bind(WidgetA.class).in(Singleton.class);
```

As written, it will be lazily created - it will only exist after it is first requested, but then every time it is requested, it will be the same instance and will not be created from scratch.

Comment: Thanks Colin, it's exactly what I was looking for! AssistedInject wiki page presents the problem exactly the same way I was asking my question!

Answer (score 2):

To echo [Colin's correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55773619/1426891), Assisted Injection is the way to go, and Guice has offered Assisted Injection (through a separate dependency/JAR) since 2.0. You can read more about Guice's implementation on the [Guice wiki AssistedInject page](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AssistedInject), but I wouldn't have anything example-wise beyond what Colin wrote.

One alternative you can consider is in [AutoFactory](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/factory), which code-generates factory implementations for you. (It's part of Google Auto, a suite of code generators for Java that creates annotation implementations, services, immutable value objects, and factories.) It's the de facto standard for Dagger, but applies to any JSR-330 framework including Guice.

---

Regarding your question #1, I'll diverge from Colin to say that what you're looking for is inherently somewhat dangerous: If `@Singleton` objects exist for the lifetime of your app, but your WidgetA Factory takes a Container, then it is possible for your WidgetA to exist before your Container is ready or for it to exist after your Container is destroyed.

If your WidgetA Container is also `@Singleton`, then you can create WidgetA without a Factory, and everything goes well: You can skip the Factory, bind the Container, bind WidgetA normally, and inject a `Provider<WidgetA>` (available without extra configuration) to delay the creation of WidgetA until you're ready.

If your real request is for WidgetA to exist exactly as long as the Container exists, but for WidgetA/B/C to all use the same Container and WidgetA for that time, you can consider [a child injector](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/Injector.html#createChildInjector-java.lang.Iterable-) where you bind your Container and Widgets. This way each Container gets its own WidgetA, each injection of WidgetA is consistent within that container, and you'll dispose of the WidgetA when you get a new Container. Of course, if your Container only starts being available after your Injector is working and is consistent after that, you can use that child injector as your main injector and have WidgetA work after that.

If your WidgetA depends on a Container that doesn't start off as available, be careful: That might be a "scope-widening injection", because your Container will live on as `@Singleton` within WidgetA even if it would otherwise be garbage-collected. This could be a memory leak at best, and could cause weird errors where multiple Containers exist within your application. You could use a stateful Module as you've been using, but in any case be very careful.

Comment: Agreed, thanks for thinking about the questions as related, I just read them as individual points sharing some code.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. Very good points that will feed my thoughts on the topic, indeed. I like the idea of using the child injector as a bubble of consistency.

Comment: Good suggestion about using AutoFactory. Guice itself even recommends it: "Consider using AutoFactory instead of AsistedInject. AutoFactory is conceptually easier to understand and requires less boilerplate." I have switched to using AutoFactory and one big advantage is that you do not have to add a (non-straightforward) binding.